# function unique change the data type of columns in data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

Suppose I have a dataframe, and get the unqiue values of one column:

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4), b = c('1','2','3','x'))
b = unique(df$b)

> b
[1] 1 2 3 x
Levels: 1 2 3 x
```

When I try to concatenate the unique vector b and an additional value:

```
c(b, 'xx')
```

It returns

```
> c(b, 'xx')
[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "xx"
```

Is there a way to get the original values in the dataframe?
like:

```
[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "x"  "xx"
```

Comment: @akrun yeah, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert to `character` and then concatenate to avoid coercing to integer storage values for the `factor` 'b'

```
c(as.character(unique(b$b)), 'xx')
#[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "x"  "xx"
```

---

Or while creating the `data.frame`, use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` (by default it is `TRUE`) to avoid converting the columns with character elements to `factor` class

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4), b = c('1','2','3','x'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now, the OP's code would work

```
c(unique(b$b), 'xx')
```